# Language links shown enabled for pre-translated nodes

Tags: i18n-l10n

The current snapshot below is of a node which was edited before I installed i18n. So when I go to edit that node "Translate" tab does not appear.

I've many nodes like this. The problem in such nodes is that in the language switcher block, all languages are shown enabled even though translations aren't available.

**What is the solution? Should I simply resave such nodes created before i18n was installed?**

So in this current snapshot, all non-English languages should have been shown as striked as I've not enabled translation for this node.

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually saving those pre-existing nodes does it. Untranslated languages are shown striked out.